# How to track Page Visit with Query String in Sitecore 9 Analytics?

Tags: experience-analytics, reporting

I am using Sitecore 9.0 update 2, and want to track the Page visits with query string. Currently all pages are tracked without query string and my requirement is to track page visit as new page, if it is with dynamic query string.

[image]

However, I have multiple page hits with unique query string of `/Search.aspx` page, but it all track under one page called `/Search.aspx`.

Comment: Have you looked into creating a custom dimension? You could check Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.FlexibleMetrics.Pages.PageMetrics, Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation for inspiration. Also: https://emanueleciriachi.net/sitecore-analytics-dimensions-segments/